# Hooking android classes with Xposed

Tags: java, android, debugging, hook, xposed

I'm trying to hook into the *android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic* method using the Xposed framework. How do I hook into methods that are, as to the best of my knowledge, are dynamically linked such as any of Android's native bluetooth classes? I was able to find the class in jdb and print it's variables as follows:

```
> stop in android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic
Set breakpoint android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic
> 
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", 
android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(), line=926 bci=0

main[1] dump characteristic.mValue
 characteristic.mValue = {
 116, 101, 115, 116, 49, 51, 51
 }
```

However, when I try to hook the class using the Xposed framework I receive the following error:

```
I/Xposed  (11661): Loaded app: com.macdom.ble.blescanner
E/Xposed  (11661): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt#writeCharacteristic()#bestmatch
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(XposedHelpers.java:440)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at com.example.test.xposed3.Xposed3.handleLoadPackage(Xposed3.java:34)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$2.beforeHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:116)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:314)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
E/Xposed  (11661):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
I/Xposed  (11661): Calling com.macdom.ble.blescanner.a onStart()
```

Here is my code which causes the *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError* error:

```
package com.example.test.xposed3;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;
import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findClass;

import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam;

public class Xposed3 implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.macdom.ble.blescanner"))
            return;

        XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);

        findAndHookMethod("com.macdom.ble.blescanner.a", lpparam.classLoader, "onStart", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                XposedBridge.log("Calling com.macdom.ble.blescanner.a onStart()");
            }
        });

        Class<?> BluetoothGatt = findClass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt", lpparam.classLoader);
        Method writeCharacteristic = XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(BluetoothGatt, "writeCharacteristic");
        XposedBridge.hookMethod(writeCharacteristic, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                XposedBridge.log("Calling android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt writeCharacteristic()");
            }
        });
    }
}
```